# Establish a connection bgetween node js and react-native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

So I'm trying to make an app that lets me send files from my computer to an app on my phone but I don't know how to connect the react-native app and the node/express server or how I can send a relatively large file over the server. Can someone please help cause I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: android support fetch api()

Comment: You can use the useEffect hook for that. In this hook, you can insert code to connect to an API/node/express server (using fetch but the axios library is easier) and get the data you need. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you understand the minimal concepts of a RESTful API since you tagged this post with Express. React-native can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) from where you can make requests on the client side using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). You can make your request similar to:

```
var request= new FormData();
request.append('file', csvFile);

axios.post(URL, request)
     .then(response => {})
     .catch(error => {})
```